# Can't connect to MSSQL instance in AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, networking

I am new to RDS. I have created MS SQL 2017 RDS instannce on 1433 port and whenever i try to connect to that instance from my local machine i get this error:

Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 258)

Server name:
XXX.XXXXXXX.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433

I can't even ping the instance from my local machine.
I also tried to ping it from EC2 instance, but it didn't work out also.

Comment: Could you tell me what your RDS security group settings are?

Comment: Type: Custom TCP Rule,
        Protocol: TCP,
                  Port: 1433,
                          Source: 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: 1.) Are you using VPN 2.) check if you can netcat to the RDS instance ( nc -zv RDSIP PORT 3.) If the port timeouts then check the security group and the ACL rules...99% of problems with connectivity are those three cases...

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: You would definitely want to lock down that security group. Allowing any IP to connect to your database instance is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that my ornization security team has blocked port 1433 from our ornization's AWS central account using a Cloud formation template that rolled out to all accounts in the ornization.